# flutter_bloc subwidget closes the bloc of the parent widget

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am using the flutter_bloc package.

I have a page with a tabbar.
The page creates a bloc and provides it to the widgets, which are used as tab content.

```
class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  MyBloc _myBloc;
  ...

  Widget _buildTabBar() {
  ...

    var children = [
    _buildFirstTab()
    _buildSecondTab(),
    ];

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: DefaultTabController(
      length: children.length,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(75.0),
            child: AppBar(
              bottom: TabBar(isScrollable: true, tabs: tabs),
            )),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: children,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  }
..
}

Widget _buildSecondTab() {
  if (_myBloc == null) {
    _myBloc = MyBloc(<..initialdata..>);
  }
  _myBloc.add(LoadServerDataEvent());

  return BlocProvider<MyBloc>(create: (_) => _myBloc, child: SecondTab());
}
```

The widget on the second tab gets the bloc from the BlocProvider and uses it.

```
class _SecondTabState extends State<SecondTab> {
  MyBloc _myBloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myBloc = BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>(context);
    super.initState();
  }
```

My problem is that the block is automatically closed when I switch between the tabs.

This is kind of strange, because the block is still used on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are doing a couple of things wrong:

1. if you want your `bloc` to be accessible in both first and second tab you should wrap the whole tab bar with it,
2. that's very odd that you keep an instance of a bloc in `_MyScreenState` and do some magic with lazy init singeltone `if (_myBloc == null) _myBloc = MyBloc()`,
3. The `_myBloc.add(LoadServerDataEvent());` in most cases should be triggered in `initState` method of the `_SecondTabState` .
4. That's very unusal that a `bloc` gets initial data from the UI. If you want to build your architecture using `blocs` this initial data should come from another `bloc`.

But if you want to provide an existing `bloc` to the second tab and prevent it from being closed you should use:

```
BlocProvider.value(
  value: _myBloc,
  child: SecondTab(),
);
```

Instead:

```
BlocProvider<MyBloc>(create: (_) => _myBloc, child: SecondTab());
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

1. 2. Thats some old code. In the first implementation i had got 2 blocs, and the second needs some data from the first. It´s a stupid implementation. I corrected it.

3. Ok thanks.

4. I did not have blocs in the whole application. In this case the screen gets an ID that is not from a block. This bloc needs the ID to load the data.